# After an edit, the bounty message disappears from the front-end

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, suggested-edits, bounties

I suggested an edit for a question with a bounty on it. I stayed on the page, and saw the "An edit has been made to this page"-message coming in. I clicked on it. Then, the bounty message disappeared! This is front-end, with a refresh, the bounty message was there again.

Sadly, I didn't make a screenshot of it, but you can imagine what it would look like.

The question: [Curl PUT request with file upload to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17012173/1544337)

Comment: I have experienced this before, just didn't find a good way to express it. It is reproducible by going to a post with a banner notice, like a bounty message or close notice, then click on "new answer" or "new edit" messages when they come in. You will then see the banner notice disappears.